# Unable to set SameSite attribute on cookie using JavaScript in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, samesite

I have an issue setting a cookie with SameSite=none using JavaScript.

I have a client's site which pulls in content from our site into an iFrame.  I need to be able to set a cookie on the user (of the client's site)'s machine which will remember a layout preference the next time the user visits the iFrame.

I have the following code which works fine in non-Chrome browsers:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) { 
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

However, if I add in a line (highlighted below) to add the SameSite and Secure attributes, the cookie is not set (in any browser):

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) { 
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    **if (c_name == "preferenceCookie") { c_value += ";SameSite=None;Secure" };**
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something stupendously obvious, but this is driving me mad.  (Or can it just not be done?)

(Oh - and it's  my first post - please be gentle!)

Thanks.